# React conditional rendering video player

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am developing a video based timeline where each video will be played automatically while scrolling.

I'm only showing one video at a time when it scrolls into view, and then I'm removing DOM video node as it scrolls out and thats working perfectly fine.

```
{this.state.playing == key &&
    <video autoPlay muted loop>
        <source src={"/static/webm/videos/"+video.webm} />
    </video>
}
```

The problem I have are slow networks, if a user has slow internet connection and keeps on scrolling every removed video they scrolled past even though no longer existing in the DOM tree continues to be downloaded which causes the website to very quickly come to a halt and waste my resources.

As you can see in here when I tested my site with dev tools and throttling enabled:
[image]

So my question is how do i stop video from being downloaded in the background after its been removed from the DOM before finishing the download?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the built-in video support in the browser then there is no way to control the amount of data that's being buffered. It depends on the browser implementation and there is no API to control it.

Your best bet here is to use another player implementations which support these functionalities like [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/wiki), [Bitmovin Player](http://www.bitmovin.com/)